# Accessing an array element directly vs. assigning it to a variable

Tags: language-agnostic, performance

Performance-wise, is it better to access an array element 'directly' multiple times, or assign its value to a variable and use that variable? Assuming I'll be referencing the value several times in the following code.

The reasoning behind this question is that, accessing an array element presumably involves some computing cost each time it is done, without requiring extra space. On the other hand, storing the value in a variable eliminates this access-cost, but takes up extra space.

```
// use a variable to store the value
Temp = ArrayOfValues(0)
If Temp > 100 Or Temp < 50 Then
    Dim Blah = Temp
    ...

// reference the array element 'directly'
If ArrayOfValues(0) > 100 Or ArrayOfValues(0) < 50 Then
    Dim Blah = ArrayOfValues(0)
    ...
```

I know this is a trivial example, but assuming we're talking about a larger scale in actual use (where the value will be referenced many times) at what point is the tradeoff between space and computing time worth considering (if at all)?

Comment: An optimizing compiler is going to make this utterly moot for HLLs. If you're using assembly or have optimizations turned off, registers are faster than cache, so you should load frequently used values into registers as much as possible. In general, I think the tipping point between register pressure and the memory hierarchy is probably an empirical matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead in memory consumption is very limited because for reference types it's just a pointer (couple of bytes) and most value types also require just a few bytes.

Arrays are very efficient structures in most languages. Getting to an index doesn't involve any lookup but just some math (each array slot takes 4 bytes so the 11th slot is at offset 40). Then there is probably a bit of overhead for bounds checking. Allocating the memory for a new local var and freeing it requires a bit of cpu cycles as well. So in the end it also depends how many array lookups you eliminate by copying to a local var.

Fact is that you really need exceptionally crappy hardware or have really big loops for this to be really important and if it is run a decent test on it. I personally choose often for the seperate variable as I find that it makes the code more readible.

Your example is odd btw since you do 2 array lookups before you create the local var :)
This makes more sense (elimination 2 more lookups)

```
Dim blah = ArrayOfValues(0)
if blah > 100 or blah < 50 then
...
```

Answer (score 8):

This is tagged language agnostic, but I don't really believe that it is.  This post answers the C and C++ version of the question.

An optimizing compiler can take care of "naked" array accesses; in C or C++ there's no reason to think that the compiler wouldn't remember the value of a memory location if no functions were called in between.  E.g.

```
int a = myarray[19];
int b = myarray[19] * 5;
int c = myarray[19] / 2;
int d = myarray[19] + 3;
```

However, if myarray is not just defined as int[] but is actually something "fancy", especially some user defined container type with a function `operator[]()` defined in another translation unit, then that function *must* be called each time the value is requested (since the function is returning the data at location in memory and the local function doesn't know that the result of the function is intended to be constant).

Even with 'naked' arrays though, if you access the same thing multiple times around function calls, the compiler similarly must assume that the value has been changed (even if it can remember the address itself).  E.g.

```
int a = myarray[19];
NiftyFunction();
int b = myarray[19] * 8;
```

There's no way that the compiler can know that myarray[19] will have the same value before and after the function call.

So- generally speaking, if you know that a value is constant through the local scope, "cache" it in a local variable.  You can program defensively and use assertions to validate this condition you've put on things:

```
int a = myarray[19];
NiftyFunction();
assert(myarray[19] == a);
int b = a * 8;
```

A final benefit is that it's much easier to inspect the values in a debugger if they're not buried in an array somewhere.

Comment: +1 for "This is tagged language agnostic, but I don't really believe that it is." The C# answer could well be different in certain ways, but I'm ill-qualified to offer it.